# How to add bullet to div title?

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

Is it possible to add a bullet like this (•), to div title?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to do it from javascript code (react) and it writes in the code "?" sign,  and NOT •

```html
<div title="I want bullet">Hover me</div>
```

Comment: Does adding `Alt+7` on your `title` attribute work?

Comment: `title="• I want bullet"`?

Comment: Try code &#8226;  with title

Comment: Not working from javascript.

Comment: can you share you js code to show what you are doing to achieve it ?

Comment: in JS (react) you can always use the unicode version: `"\u2022 I want bullet"`

Answer (score 2):

We can use before psuedo element on the element to achieve this.

**.html**

```
/* Added a title class to the element */
<div class="title" title="I want bullet">Hover me</div>
```

**.css**

```
.title:before {
   content:"\A";
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   border-radius:50%;
   background: #000;
   margin-right: 5px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Why do this if you can simply just use `&#8226;` in title ?

Comment: change padding to margin, and you don't really need the \A

Comment: @Douglas Santos, Edited. Thanks

Comment: @NipunJain, The question is for the div element.

Comment: I think in `div title` was asked, am I misunderstanding it

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can use a **HTML entity** to replace characters which aren't present on your keyboard.
This is simply down by looking up the character your after from a reference page like

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

write down it's decimal value - which is **8226** for a bullet point - put a **&#** before and a **;** after this value and finally add this to your string.
So

```
<div title="I want bullet">Hover me</div>
```

becomes

```
<div title="I want bullet">&#8226; Hover me</div>
```

Unfortunately though such numbers are hard to remember so there's the possibility to reference such an entitiy by it's name too. The entitiy name for the bullet point character is **bull** which you can add to your string like `&bull;`

If you want to add the bullet point to a `<div>` element using Javascript you need to use it's **.innerHTML** property.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("bullet").innerHTML = "&#8226; Hover me";
```

```html
<div id="bullet"></div>
```

Comment: In what way are you trying to add the bullet point via javascript?

Comment: I've refined my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div title="&#8226; I want bullet">Hover me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create bullet in other elements by  using the default CSS of `li` element.

```
div{
  display: list-item;
  list-style: list-item;
}
```